# Horizontal line inline-block IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I would like to put 3 horizontal line in a row.
Does anyone know how to put an horizontal line displaying in inline-block in IE7 ?

Here is my CSS:

```
hr.small {
    width: 28.9%;
    margin-right: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    height: 3px;
    border: 0px;
    color: #7c8690;
    background-color: #7c8690;
}
```

but it doesnt works.

here is the JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/sRuz3/6/

If anyone has a solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This any good? http://jsfiddle.net/R49YG/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/eq3Z2/

It works in IE7 also.

Granted, they aren't HRs. They are DIVs. Trying to render the HR as an inline element
is tripping up IE7 but I don't know of a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be inline-block? Can you not simply float them and set a height if necessary?

**Edit - Example:**

```
hr.small {

    float:left;
    width: 28.9%;
    margin-right: 6px; /* Choice: Use border instead or halve the margin for IE7 and lowwer (double margin float bug). */
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #7c8690;

}
```

**Edit again - Question:**

Is this going in a fluid layout and how big is the container? You are setting a dynamic width but a fixed margin, this will cause issues in small scale and introduce unwanted white space to the far right in large scale. If it is a fixed area then consider using a fixed width.

Comment: I didnt try to put them in float yet, I would like to find if there is a easier way first.

Comment: Dosnt get much easier than float my friend :)

It is fairly reliable cross browser and generally does what you ask it too, given a little experience. Updated my answer with example.

Comment: The hr are in a fixed layout, I apply a fix width on them. thanks for the advices. The float left seems doesnt works:/

Comment: How strange. I cannot get it to work with IE Tester although it is not the most reliable piece of software, much like IE7 : /

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a solution if you can wrap the `hr`s in `div`s.

Set the div's to `display:inline` (we could use `span`s instead but `hr`s are not valid in `span`s)¹ and also give the `div`s hasLayout via `zoom:1`

See http://jsfiddle.net/YqKDJ/1/

---

¹ As an aside, there's a reason why `hr`s are not valid in `span`s and it's relevant here. An `hr` is not primarily a way of drawing a horizontal line - it has a specific semantic meaning of "Thematic break". It makes no sense to have two or more `hr` elements with no content betwwen them - there's nothing for the second thematic break to break from. If you want multiple horizontal lines for presentational purposes, you should use CSS to create them, along the lines of @Cynthia's answer.